# Amazon S3 signing works however it gets forbidden

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
module.exports = function (express, router) {
    var _ = require('lodash'),
        aws = require('aws-sdk'),
        AWSConfig = require('../../config/AWSConfig.json');

    router.route('/resource/file/sign')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            var bucket = "myTestBucket";
            aws.config.update({accessKeyId: AWSConfig.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWSConfig.AWS_SECRET_KEY});

            var s3 = new aws.S3();
            var options = {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: req.body.name,
                Expires: 60,
                ContentType: req.body.type,
                ACL: 'private'
            };

            s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', options, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.send('Error with S3')
                }
                res.json({
                    signed_request: data,
                    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + bucket + '/' + req.body.name
                })
            })

        });


    return router;
};
```

This request returns a `signed_request` and works correctly.

However when I attempt to upload to the url I get `forbidden` in my `OPTIONS` request.

I also get a `CORS` error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

This is my first time trying to use Amazon S3.

### Update

I have no attempted to edit the permissions and the cors headers now the cors error is gone but I am still forbidden to upload.

Here is my configuration:

**Bucket policy**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::learningbank-test/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                        "public-read"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Permissions:

[image]

Console error (on my end)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) rules on a bucket. See [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) for details and examples.

Also, make sure the bucket permissions allow the given user to write to it. Start from [Introduction to S3 access control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-managing-access-s3-resources.html) and [Using bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html).

**Update**

You have defined `PutObject` grants in your bucket policy when [canned ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) in the request is equal to `public-read`. The information is carried over using `s3:x-amz-acl` header in HTTP request.

However, you have defined ACL equal to `private` in your code. Try setting it to `public-read` to make it match the bucket policy statement.